# Why there is compiler error: Cannot convert void to string, where as there is no casting happening

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm not sure why there is compiler error, `Argument 1 Cannot convert 'void' to 'string'`, where as there is no casting happening. Below code creates a list of methods:

```
void FunctionList(string srcBucket, List<List<string>> pdfFileList, IAmazonS3 s3client)
{
    List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
    foreach (var list in pdfFileList)
       list.Add(RenameFilesAsync(srcBucket, list, s3client).Wait()); // Getting error here
}

public async Task RenameFilesAsync(string srcBucket, List<string> pdfFiles, IAmazonS3 s3client)
{
  //Some code here
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you believe the result of `RenameFilesAsync(srcBucket, list, s3client).Wait()` is, and how would you expect that to be added to a list?

Comment: And are you sure you want to be calling `list.Add` instead of `actions.Add`? (You're not using your `actions` variable at all.)

Comment: Oops! Thanks Jon Skeet. That's the mistake

Answer (score 2):

Your signature on `RenameFilesAsync` returns just a `Task`, not `Task<T>`.  If you don't specify a type, it will not return a value, so it looks like `void`.

Here's the link to the async return types:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/async-return-types

Comment: `public async Task RenameFilesAsync(...)` 

should be 

`public async Task<string> RenameFilesAsync(...)` for it to return a string. I think OP just put it into the wrong list though, the List<action> will accept a void type. Jon Skeet pointed it out in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this line

```
list.Add(RenameFilesAsync(srcBucket, list, s3client).Wait());
```

with two lines

```
string s = await RenameFilesAsync(srcBucket, list, s3client).Wait();
list.Add(s);
```

Then it should be easier to debug

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that didn't work because I was using wrong variable